# Get only closest documents using mongodb geoNear or near

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm getting crazy to return closest Venues from a specific point using MongoDB. It is the first time I work on it so I'm totally new to this practice.

What I did at the beginning is to create a 2DIndex of my Venue collection.

Now I'm trying to get Venues in a range of 500 meters from a specific point and the code is this:

```js
    Venue.find({ location:
        {
            $near: [ 52.3835443 , 4.8353073 ],
            $maxDistance: 0.5 / 6371
        }
    }, function (err, venues) {
        return venues;
    });
```

Unfortunately it return all documents.

The Venue Model has the field for location like this:

```js
"location": {
  "type": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "coordinates": [{ "type": "Number" }]
}
```

And all my Venues are like this:

```js
{
 "name": "name",
 "address": "address",
 "location": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [50.1981668, 7.9943994999]
 }
}
```

I also tried using `$geoNear` but I always receive all documents and not only those in 500 meters distance.

EDIT:

Mongo version is 3.2;

index:

```js
{
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
        "location": "2dsphere"
    },
    "name": "location_2dsphere",
    "ns": "mydb.Venue",
    "2dsphereIndexVersion": 2
}
```

document as wrote above:

```js
{
 "name": "A name",
 "address": "An address",
 "location": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [50.1981668, 7.9943994999]
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you run an aggregation `$geoNear` and post the reported distances? Also noting that the sample document you keep giving is nowhere near 500 meters, and is in fact `426728` meters away. Doesn't reproduce for me. Note if your query coordinates are in GeoJSON the distances are always directly in meters rather than radians. So no need to convert if you keep to GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

The $maxDistance operator constrains the results of a geospatial $near or $nearSphere query to the specified distance. The measuring units for the maximum distance are determined by the coordinate system in use. For GeoJSON point object, specify the distance in meters, not radians. [ref here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/)

When I was executing this query I got:

> planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query

so added **$geometry ** into query body

```
Venue.find({ location:
      {
    $near: {
       $geometry : {
           type : "Point" ,
           coordinates : [ 52.3835443 , 4.8353073 ]},

       $maxDistance : 500}}}
    }, function (err, venues) {
        return venues;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This way return all my documents... and not only those within that range unfortunately.

Comment: that's interesting. Could you post document example (as is) and db.collection.getIndexes() output [please add to question body]? what version of mongo?

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo added geometry into query - please check

Comment: Just tried and it is continuing to get all my documents... tried to put `0` in `$maxDistance` and it always return all documents... I can not really understand what is wrong in here... just followed original documentations...

Comment: Just tried to follow the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/.
I swapped `lng` and `lat` as described.
Did everything like described, it continue to return all documents... Maybe my Venues are not indexed properly?

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo just for test sake run this query in mongo console - maybe there is a stupid error.....

Comment: Just did it too using `$geoNear` and it return no documents this time... I'm just wondering if coordinates should be: `[ LNG, LAT ]` like requested by `$near`, because in that case all my documents are `[ LAT, LNG ]` (like all the world use to write...).

Comment: Just converted all my `[lat, lng]` to be `[lng, lat]`. From Mongo shell it is working fine... not working from express project... Using exactly the same code... I'm quite confused now.

Comment: Hi if you get no documents using Geonear check coordinates and distance in my example there is a fake of e

Comment: I get correct results using geoNear from mongo shell. The issue is that I get all my documents using the same code in Express...